# Kotlin: Mediaplayer: Couldn't open content://com.android.externalstorage.: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.ext

Tags: kotlin

Not able to play a song stored as a Uri in SQLite,
The file selected by below function is playing well

```
private fun selectMusicFile() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "audio/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio"), 123)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (data?.data != null){
            musicFileUri = data?.data!!
            binding.tvMusicFile.text = data?.data!!.toString()
            setupMediaPlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

The same uri is stored in SQLite as a text field. When i try to play this uri then i get error
here is code for setting up the mediaplayer using uri from SQLite which gets store in the textview

```
  private fun setupMediaPlayer() {
    val vUri = Uri.parse(binding.tvMusicFile.text.toString())
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, vUri)
    mediaPlayer.prepare()
```

}

it fails at setDataSource

setupMediaPlayer() works well when called from onActivityResult, but fails when called from other place e.i. after fetching uri from SQLite table

Can someone please help

here is error log

W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMusic%2FThe%20Man%20Machine%2FThe%20Model.mp3: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMusic%2FThe%20Man%20Machine%2FThe%20Model.mp3 from pid=23509, uid=10264 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxx, PID: 23509
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/com.xxx.configure.ConfigureActivity}: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1172)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1160)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1078)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1003)
at com.xxx.configure.ConfigureActivity.setupMediaPlayer(ConfigureActivity.kt:189)
at com.xxx.configure.ConfigureActivity.onCreate(ConfigureActivity.kt:115)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

Comment: There is something strange happening, although there is always a reason behind in coding but i am not able to figure it out, what is happening is that the code same worked last night and today morning it worked once and then started giving this error without any change in code